# grouping the same value in upper case and lower case with select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the below table **InputParameterName** column contains **Product1** ( **P** upper case) and **pRoduct1** ( **R** upper case).

Table1 :

```
InputParameterName  Period  PeriodInput
Product1             2017   25704
Product1             2018   25704
pRoduct1             2017   16
pRoduct1             2018   16
pRoduct1             2017   57.6
pRoduct1             2018   57.6
pRoduct1             2017   40.5
pRoduct1             2018   40.5
```

My query:

```
SELECT InputParameterName, Period, SUM(CAST(PeriodInput AS FLOAT)) PeriodInput  
FROM Table1         
GROUP BY InputParameterName, Period
```

Result :

```
InputParameterName  Period  PeriodInput
Product1                    2017    25818.1
pRoduct1                    2018    25818.1
```

In the result you can see InputParameterName column has **Product1** ( **P** upper case) and **pRoduct1** ( **R** upper case).

Is there any way to get both as same, either **Product1** or **pRoduct1** (exact values without applying any character case conversion) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lower()` or `upper()`:

```
SELECT MIN(InputParameterName) as InputParameterName, Period,
       SUM(CAST(PeriodInput AS FLOAT)) PeriodInput  
FROM Table1         
GROUP BY LOWER(InputParameterName), Period;
```

The use `LOWER()` in the `GROUP BY` defines the *columns*.  It is not used in the `SELECT` so you always get a value in the data.

If you don't care about the case, then you should look into setting the [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) of the column, table, or database so case is ignored in expressions involving strings.

EDIT:

If the above result returns two rows, then case is not the problem.  You probably have hidden characters.  the most likely are spaces, so you can try:

```
GROUP BY LOWER(REPLACE(InputParameterName, ' ', '')), Period;
```

Hopefully, the hidden spaces are no more complicated than spaces.

EDIT II:

I get it now.  You want the two rows, you just want the values to be the same.  Then window functions can do what you want:

```
SELECT MIN(InputParameterName) OVER (PARTITION BY LOWER(InputParameterName)),
       Period, SUM(CAST(PeriodInput AS FLOAT)) as PeriodInput  
FROM Table1         
GROUP BY InputParameterName, Period;
```

Comment: I cant do any conversion  to Lower or Upper, I want to get any one among the two :(

Comment: @thingguy . . . Exactly.  This only does the conversion for the `GROUP BY`.  The `SELECT` returns one of the values actually in the data.

Comment: It should return 2 rows, because group by clause contains periods column as well and table has data for 2 periods 2017 and 2018. But the problem here is getting different name Product1 and pRoduct1, I want to get any one of them in both rows.

Comment: @Linoff its working fine with PARTITION, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `LOWER()`:

```
SELECT
    LOWER(InputParameterName) AS InputParameterName,
    Period,
    SUM(CAST(PeriodInput AS FLOAT)) PeriodInput  
FROM Table1         
GROUP BY
    LOWER(InputParameterName),
    Period
```

To be strictly ANSI compliant, we should not use a function of a column in the `GROUP BY` clause.  In this case, we could use a derived table:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        LOWER(InputParameterName) AS InputParameterName,
        Period,
        PeriodInput
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT
    InputParameterName,
    Period,
    SUM(CAST(PeriodInput AS FLOAT)) PeriodInput  
FROM cte       
GROUP BY
    InputParameterName,
    Period
```

Comment: LOWER(InputParameterName) will convert all the values to lower case.. I cant do any conversion, need to get any one among the two (Product1 or product1)

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Update your question and show us what you have in mind.

Comment: @thingguy As far as I know, if you don't use `LOWER()` or `UPPER()` to handle the case sensitivity issue, then the only alternative would be Gordon's suggestion to use a case insensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

BY Using Row_Number() and Partitioning over 'Period 'Column you get desired result

```
;With cte(InputParameterName,Period,PeriodInput)
    AS
    (
    SELECT 'Product1', 2017,25704 Union all
    SELECT 'Product1', 2018,25704 Union all
    SELECT 'product1', 2017,16    Union all
    SELECT 'product1', 2018,16    Union all
    SELECT 'product1', 2017,57.6  Union all
    SELECT 'product1', 2018,57.6  Union all
    SELECT 'product1', 2017,40.5  Union all
    SELECT 'product1', 2018,40.5
    )
    SELECT InputParameterName,Period,PeriodInput FRom
    (
    SELECT  InputParameterName,
            Period,
            CAST(SUM(PeriodInput)OVER(Partition by Period Order BY Period) AS FLOAT)AS PeriodInput,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by Period Order BY Period)AS Seq From cte    
    )DT
    WHERE DT.Seq=1
```

OutPut

```
InputParameterName  Period  PeriodInput
--------------------------------------
product1            2017    25818.1
product1            2018    25818.1
```